# Is there a way from NodeJS to get Tron Blockchain transaction details?

Tags: node.js, api, blockchain, tron

I would need to get, passing the Transaction ID, the from/to address, the value of token transferred, and the type of token passed?

I've found so far the API from Tron Grid, i have already tried the
[https://api.trongrid.io/v1/transactions/TRANSACTION_ID/events'](https://api.trongrid.io/v1/transactions/TRANSACTION_ID/events%27)
THis call returns the two wallet addresses, and the amount (uint256), but not the type of token passed.
Is there any way?
I also found the tronweb package, but i can't find any documentation about it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can keep map of contract addresses and token types. I'm not sure this is relevant to you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Trongrid API has two POST endpoints for getting details by transaction id (hash).

https://api.trongrid.io/wallet/gettransactioninfobyid

https://api.trongrid.io/wallet/gettransactionbyid

the body is the same for both requests - should contains the transaction hash:

```
 {"value": "440140edbd1e9be5a0a78605018d5803b2388e080227337b435a826b127cd5d8"}
```

To get the token type for transfer you can use first endpoint - trc20 transfers are in the response.log array and contain 'address' field - the hex address of contract of the token. Then you can get token info by this contract address.

You need API key to use this API. See docs for more details:

https://developers.tron.network/v3.7/reference/transaction-info-by-id

https://developers.tron.network/v3.7/reference/walletgettransactionbyid